# Keyboard shortcut for "Replace/Find" while doing a find and replace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

After opening the Find/Replace dialog in elipse I would like to be able to perform the "Replace/Find" operation using a keyboard shortcut.  Is there a way to do this?

The next match can be found done using `ret`, and the previous by using `shift+ret`, but I can't seem to find anyway to do either Replace or Replace/Find.  Currently the only way I know to do this is to interact with the dialog using the mouse.

More generally I would like to be able to do simple regex find and replace operations in eclipse without needing to use the mouse.  If there is another way to do this that avoids using the Find/Replace dialog that would be fine as well.

This is the Find/Replace dialog in eclipse that I am trying to interact with:

[image: Find/Replace Dialog]

Comment: There are two plugins that may eventually work for this: "Emacs+" and "Find Bar".  Emacs+ is not currently supported on Juno, and Find Bar is in alpha and has not added replace functionality yet.

Comment: I recommend you to use Glance to search in open document instead of find/replace. It has all you want for fast finding a sentence

Answer (score 2):

Such feature does not exist at present (afaik).

I submitted a feature request:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449004

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+k finds next, never seen a find/replace shortcut though

Comment: Yeah, the find next command can be found in the standard keyboard preferences, but there is no replace or replace/find option in there.